# how to make for-loop order to rbind all excel files in the same directory

Tags: r, for-loop

i want to rbind all excel files (regardless the total amount of files) in a directory and make a new column that is filled with the name of files, so then i could identify where the data came from. For example, i have template of file like this

```
promo  stock
  a     200
  b     200
  c     200
```

to be like this

```
store  promo  stock
file1    a     200
file1    b     200
file1    c     200
file2    a     200
file2    b     200
file2    c     200
file3    a     200
file3    b     200
file3    c     200
```

how to make a for-loop order for this case? thanx in advance

Comment: what are the names of the excel files?

Comment: file1.xlsx,file2.xlsx and so on.
Those files have the same template

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888757/how-can-i-read-multiple-excel-files-into-r or the more general https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519464/how-to-import-multiple-excel-files-with-multiple-sheet-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771402/how-to-read-in-multiple-xlsx-files-to-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159387/importing-multiple-excel-files-with-filenames-in-r etc etc etc

Comment: if my excel file has several sheets in it and i want to merge it all first and then merge it with other excel file, how to do it?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto - I imagine the first step is to start writing or adapting some code, and then ask a specific question if something goes wrong. One of the questions I've linked above ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519464/how-to-import-multiple-excel-files-with-multiple-sheet-in-r ) is nearly exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 3):

We could find the full path name to the files and then use `lapply` to read each file with `readxl::read_excel` and add a new column `store` with the name of the file

```
file_paths <- list.files("/path/to/files", pattern = ".xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)

do.call(rbind, lapply(file_paths, function(x) 
    transform(readxl::read_excel(x), store = sub(".xlsx$", "", basename(x)))))

#  promo stock store                                            
#1     a   200 file1
#2     b   200 file1
#3     c   200 file1
#4     a   200 file2
#5     b   200 file2
#6     c   200 file2
```

---

We can also use `purrr::map_df`

```
purrr::map_df(file_paths, ~transform(readxl::read_excel(.), 
                            store = sub(".xlsx$", "", basename(.))))
```

Comment: how to remove that ".xlsx" in the store column, so i just get the name without the extension?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto You could use `tools::file_path_sans_ext` to get only the file name without extension or use `sub` as updated above in the answer.

Comment: what is the difference between ".xlsx$" and ".xlsx"?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto `.xlsx$` removes `xlsx` only if it is present in the last part of the string, using it without `$` would remove it from anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it although `Reduce(rbind)` might be slow depending on how many files you have. Also you may need to modify the code to read your file based on the extension. Let me know -

```
# set working directory to where the files are using setwd()

result <- lapply(dir(), function(x) {
  cbind(store = x, read.csv(paste0(x, ".csv"), header = T, stringsAsFactors = F))
}) %>% 
  {Reduce(rbind, .)}
```

Comment: my files are in xlsx extension. Is it applicable? So then I just replace csv with xlsx?

Comment: Just use any package that lets you read xlsx and replace my `read.csv` with that.